# wrapper div of position absolute element should take its child height.css tricks

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, accessibility

My problem statement is this

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <h3>some heading</h3>
      <div class="absolute"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <h3>some other heading</h3>
      <div class="absolute"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
<style>
  .absolute{
   position:absolute}

  ul{
    position:relative }
</style>
```

Actually from accessibility perspective i have tried to implement tab structure using according DOM . But in "Mobile" view its needed that "**ul**" should take the child height . As this structure is not simple , there are multiple nesting layers. How to solve it?
`

Comment: Your `div` tags aren't closed.

Comment: sorry i ignored that while writing.now i have edited.any idea?

Comment: your question is quite unclear, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? I'm not sure because what you're asking is a bit vague: https://jsfiddle.net/ywbhtgup/ If so, let me know and I will write up a full answer.

Comment: I want my ul to take the height of the div with absolute class. Where the content of the div can change so no fixed height

Comment: I have it backwards then. I was giving the `div` the height of the parent `li`. What you want cannot be done with pure CSS since the item in question, `div`, is `position: absolute`. Also, your `div` currently is collapsed because it has no content. Since the `div` is `position: absolute`, it will not take up space in it's parent. So what you need to do using JS is grab the height of the `div` (and in this case there are two), and then take that value and assign it to the `ul`.

Comment: No  Pegues. If i give top:4px suppose to absolute element, ul is not wrapping that

Comment: UL will not wrap that. The absolute `div` will not take up space in the `ul` that affects the `ul` height.

Comment: I think you need to provide a JSFiddle or CodePen of your problem. I also think your reliance on `position:absolute` is probably what is killing your since this could be trivial otherwise.